# What is Tinbergen's "all other income when paid out" measuring?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics

In *When it all began* by [Dhaene and Barten (1989)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/02649993/6/2), the authors discuss in detail what they claim was the first ever macroeconometric model, Tinbergen's 1936 model of the Netherlands economy.

Some of their summaries of Tinbergen's variables are a bit vague though.

What, for example, is $E$, described as *"All other income, when paid out"*?

[image: All other income, when paid out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very obscure indeed. If you see his paper in [English](https://repub.eur.nl/pub/15944/) (published in 1959), you can see the following (page 43):

[image]

By checking other variables, you can confirm that the variable letters are equivalent in this and your reference. Then, $E$ stands for "*all non-wage income, taken at the moment received, instead of take when earned*".

This is a standard differentiation between the time an income has been [accrued](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/accruedincome.asp) ($Z$) and when it has actually been received ($E$).

You can see more about these definitions later on in the document. In page 49, you find an explanation on how these are calculated (19 is $Z$, 20 is $E$; see table in page 47-48):

[image]

It seems the author is assuming that income is received one further year *after* is is accrued. However, the text seem to me rather obscure. He mentions a "pamphlet regarding this working method which will be published later." (p.42). You might want to trace that one down.